# What's the max length of a ListProperty?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How many items can be stored in a ListProperty? Is there a limit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Entities are limited to 1MB in size (when encoded as a Protocol Buffer), so this provides a practical limit on the size of a list. Further, if the list is indexed, you're limited to 5000 entries before you get an exception because your entity has too many index rows.

Answer (score 10):

In my experience you will get `MemoryError` exceptions deserializing ListProperties before you hit a hard limit. That used to happen to me with 5,000 to 10,000 Key entities in the list.

Also, entities are [limited to 5,000 indexed properties](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/d5f4dcb7d00ed4c6) so 5,000 is a good maximum. (I feel like I used to have more sometimes but I don't remember exactly now.)